# this.id corresponds to variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a list of variables that correspond to numbers. I use these variables to write numbers to a "screen" in a web app I'm building for fun.

```
var zero = 0;
var one = 1;
var two = 2;
var three = 3;
var four = 4;
var five = 5;
var six = 6;
var seven = 7;
var eight = 8;
var nine = 9;
var dec = ".";
var neg = "-";
```

[image: example Image]

I used to have a long list of `onclick` functions for each of the buttons:

```
$('#a0').click(function(){
    writeInput(input, zero);
});

$('#a1').click(function(){
    writeInput(input, one);
});
$('#a2').click(function(){
    writeInput(input, two);
});
...
```

I want to convert all of these click functions into something like this:

```
$('.btnA').click(function(){
    var id = this.id;
    writeInput(input, id);
});
```

Which calls this function:

```
function writeInput(field, str){
var text = $(field).val(function(i, v){
              return v + str;
           }).text(function(i, t){
              return t + str
           }).val();
convert(text, version);
```

}

All of the buttons on the number input above have this HTML:

```
...
<a id="seven" class="btnA"><div class="inputBtn mar" id="input7">7</div></a>
<a id="eight" class="btnA"><div class="inputBtn mar" id="input8">8</div></a>
<a id="nine" class="btnA"><div class="inputBtn" id="input9">9</div></a>
...
```

My question is: Can I get the id name from the `<a id="nine" class="btnA">` and have it correspond to the `var nine = 9;`

I hope this made sense. If not please ask I will answer any questions. Thanks!

Comment: You do not really need these variables for simple number literals, do you?

Comment: Your `#a0`, `#a1`… selectors do not match the DOM snippet you posted. What are they?

Comment: Those were the old ones before I changed the id of the links. I changed the id to correspond to the variable names.

Comment: Never let code rely on *variable* names. Property names (of an object) would be OK, but variables are only "places" at runtime, their *name* is unknown (and a minifier might even change that).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an object with the ID's as keys, and you'll get numbers back:

```
var numbers = {one: 1, two: 2, three: 3, .....};

$('.btnA').click(function(){
    var id = numbers[this.id];
    writeInput(input, id);
});
```

Comment: He could also exploit the fact that his `nine` global variable is actually a property of the `window` object already: `var id = window[this.id];` However, your `numbers` object is both a better coding choice and less overall code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Really nice code as well. Also cleaned up my disgusting variable list :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use data-type attribute and write something that:

```
<a data-number="7" class="btnA"><div class="inputBtn mar" id="input7">7</div></a>

$('.btnA').click(function(){
    var number = $(this).data('number');
    writeInput(input, number);
});
```

Comment: Edited your code to use [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data) intead of `.dataset` since [it works in more browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.dataset).

Comment: @Blazemonger It seems your code not work now. Please check this: http://jsfiddle.net/c5d2t/2/

Comment: My bad, I thought `number` was a variable.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
$('.btnA').click(function() {
    var t = $(this).text(),
        n = parseInt(t, 10);
    writeInput(input, isNaN(n) ? t : n);
});
```

However, you could as well extract the number from the id attribute (just `substr` the "a") or even better use data attributes for them instead of reading the button text.